# Custom Ordering in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by, ssms

I'm trying to implement a "custom" ordering in the `ORDER BY` clause in my SQL query using a `CASE` Statement but it's giving me some funky ordering

Here is my `ORDER BY` clause so far:

**Edited to Reflect Update:**

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN 
        CheckInStatus <> 'Cancelled' AND ArrivalTime is null AND GETDATE() > DATEADD(mi,30, CAST(StartDateTime AS DATETIME))THEN 1
    WHEN 
        CheckInStatus <> 'Cancelled' AND ArrivalTime is null AND GETDATE() <= DATEADD(mi,30, CAST(StartDateTime AS DATETIME)) THEN 2
    WHEN ArrivalTime is not null THEN 3
    WHEN CheckInStatus='Cancelled' THEN 4 
    ELSE 5
    END,
    StartDateTime, ScanTechName
```

What I want to do is order the query as follows:

People who have NOT arrived (and who's appointments are not cancelled) and current time is Greater than than 30 minutes past the StartTime - these guys should be first

People who have NOT arrived (and who's appointments are not cancelled) and current time is less than or equal to 30 minutes past the StartTime - these guys appear second

Next is everyone who is checked in

Followed by Cancelled Appointments

And finally then everything else

And everything will be ordered by StartTime and Name

The issue seems to occur with 2 and 3.  These guys seem to get mixed together and I think it might have to do with my AND but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Below is the error I get in the results - I've included the `CASE` in the `ORDER BY` to visually see the issue

**Edit to Include Results:**

```
Arrival Time            | CheckIn Status | StartDateTime           | OrderStatus
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2014-08-15 08:00:07.123 | Arrived        | 2014-08-15 07:15:00.000 | 3 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2014-08-15 07:47:48.643 | Arrived        | 2014-08-15 07:30:00.000 | 2
```

So a couple of things happening

1. Since my current GETDATE() is 8/28/2014 - there shouldn't be a 2 Status for the above.  Since it's not Less than or equal to the 30 minutes past the StartDate
2. Since that's wrong in itself it could lead to this second issue - since it's marked as 2 it should be appearing before 3 not after.

Comment: can you set up sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/ please

Comment: what is the meaning of this - "CAST(StartDateTime AS DATETIME) <= DATEADD(mi,30, CAST(StartDateTime AS DATETIME))" Did you mean to use the same field here?

Comment: It's meant to be: The Start DateTime of Appoint <= 30 minutes + the Appointment Start DateTime

Comment: And as below comments pointed out that is never going to happen lol

Comment: And I've updated my original post to reflect updates and issue

Comment: It appears that the answers given have fixed your original question but you have edited your question and are asking a new question.  It is best, in this case I believe, to leave the question as is (was), and post a new question.  You'll get more attention that way anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part of your condition seems to be the cause of your problem:

```
CAST(StartDateTime AS DATETIME) > DATEADD(mi,30, CAST(StartDateTime AS DATETIME))
```

[StartDateTime] will never be greather than the same date plus 30min! Same remark for your second condition.

If that's not solving your problem, can you provide more info about the result your have with this query?

Comment: Ahh! You're absolutely right - I'll need to change it to actually be a GETDATE() - I'll edit and see if I'm still encountering any problems.  Dur moment...

Comment: And now that I've updated it to use GETDATE() rather than StartDate I'm still getting errors -.-

Comment: Can you provide an exemple of what you expect as result and what the current query returns?

Comment: Just edited my original post with updated query and some sample result displaying issue

Comment: Thank you for this update, have you copy/paste the CASE switch in the SELECT clause in order to output this result? I ask that because the ORDER clause is ascending by default (that the case of your clause) and your exemple is descending... Make sure that the query showed in the question is the same that you have tested.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple logic error.  You are comparing "StartDateTime" to ("StartDateTime" + 30 minutes), which will always return true.  I am guessing you would want to compare to the current time, which would make it look something like this:

```
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN 
    CheckInStatus <> 'Cancelled' AND ArrivalTime is null AND getdate() > DATEADD(mi,30, CAST(StartDateTime AS DATETIME))THEN 1
WHEN 
    CheckInStatus <> 'Cancelled' AND ArrivalTime is null AND getdate() <= DATEADD(mi,30, CAST(StartDateTime AS DATETIME)) THEN 2
WHEN ArrivalTime is not null THEN 3
WHEN CheckInStatus='Cancelled' THEN 4 
ELSE 5
END,
StartDateTime, ScanTechName
```

Comment: I actually edited my order by to follow the GETDATE() (rather than by StartDate) but I'm still getting some funky errors.